# Using interfaces in modules

Tags: java, kotlin, libgdx, box2d

I am trying using FirebaseDatabase in libgdx core module. I made interface but I dont know how I will use. I mean I did not see using an interface like this. I mean I want to get an example code. For example I want to send a mesaj to firebas database from menuScreen class.

Interface in Core

```
public interface FirebaseInterfaceInCore {
    public void sendMessage(String mesaj);
}
```

Class in android  implemented Interface

```
public class FirebaseAndroid implements FirebaseInterfaceInCore {

    @Override
    public void sendMessage(String mesaj) {
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
        myRef.setValue(mesaj);
    }
}
```

Louncher class of android module

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    
      initialize(new ColorKeeper(new FirebaseAndroid()), config);
    }
}
```

Class I am working on game in Core

```
class MenuScreen :Screen() {
override fun show() {}
override fun render(delta: Float) {}
```

Comment: "how I will use".  How you will use to do what?  What is it that you want to accomplish?  Simply using an interface without any context as to why is not really a meaningful question.

Comment: I mean I want to get an example code. For example I want to send a mesaj to firebas database from menuScreen class. All codes are there as you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app is main class `ColorKeeper` and the only place where you can get reference to the interface from is the constructor of this class. Then you need to store reference to this reference somewhere and later when you create your `MenuScreen` pass it there. Then you can call it.

```
class ColorKeeper {
  private FirebaseInterfaceInCore firebaseInterface;

  private createMenuScreen() {
    new MenuScreen(firebaseInterface);
  }

  public ColorKeeper(FirebaseInterfaceInCore firebaseInterface) {
    this.firebaseInterface = firebaseInterface;
  }
}

class MenuScreen {
  public MenuScreen(FirebaseInterfaceInCore firebaseInterface) {
    firebaseInterface.sendMessage("message");
  }
}
```